# Deserialising generic type fails to set property of type T

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm having some issues deserialising a JSON string to a generic type using Json.Net.

The issue that i'm having is the properties on the generic class are being deserialised correctly, in this case the `SomeStrings` property below will be populated as expected, but the `Data` property is left `null`.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on what it is that i'm missing since serialising the same type is working fine.

See the class structure below:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public List<string> SomeStrings { get; protected set; } = new List<string>();

    protected Foo()
    {

    }
}

public class GenericFoo<TBar> : Foo
{
    public TBar Data { get; private set; }

    private GenericFoo() {}

    public GenericFoo(TBar data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public GenericFoo(TBar data, params string[] someStrings) :this(data)
    {
        SomeStrings = someStrings.ToList();
    }

}

public class DataClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The code that i'm running:

```cs
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};

var response = new GenericFoo<DataClass>(new DataClass()
{
    Id = 10
}, "Test");

//serialises completely fine
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, settings); 

//Produces JSON: {"Data":{"Id":10},"SomeStrings":["Test"]}

//all properties deserialised fine, Data left null
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericFoo<DataClass>>(json, settings);
```

Comment: You don't have parameterless construcor on your class? Try making that `private` one `public`

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius - using ```ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor``` in the serialiser settings allows for a private parameterless constructor.

Comment: @cmpbedes check my [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608767/5233410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) attribute to the constructor

> Use the `JsonConstructorAttribute` to specify that a constructor should be used to create a class during deserialization.

```
public class GenericFoo<TBar> : Foo {
    public TBar Data { get; private set; }

    private GenericFoo() { }

    public GenericFoo(TBar data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public GenericFoo(TBar data, params string[] someStrings) : this(data) {
        SomeStrings = someStrings.ToList();
    }

}
```

I get the desired behavior when deserializing. Even without the settings

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var response = new GenericFoo<DataClass>(new DataClass()
        {Id = 10}, "Test");
        //serialises completely fine
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericFoo<DataClass>>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Data.Id); // Prints 10
    }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle of running code.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKWSoj)

Answer (score 1):

To deserialize your **SomeString**, simply use the **JsonProperty** like this:

```
 [JsonProperty]
 public List<string> SomeStrings { get; protected set; }
```

This does not work with the public generic attribute with private setter. It works on private or protected generic attributes though. (Maybe a bug?)

```
 [JsonProperty]
 private TBar Data { get; set; }
```

This can be solved by using a hidden property for serialization like this:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public TBar Data { get; private set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = nameof(Data))]
private TBar PrivateData
{
    get => Data;
    set => Data = value;
}
```